# .htaccess rewrite consolidation

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I currently have two rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file, and now need to add another. However, GTMetrix is already giving me an F rating here stating: *Avoid landing page redirects*

1. The first redirect adds the `www.` to the URL.
2. The second redirect adds a subdirectory to the URL.
3. The third (proposed) redirect adds the `https` to the beginning of the URL.

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
>
> #First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
>
> #Then, rewrite to /catalog
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalog [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /catalog/$1 [L]
>
> #Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
> #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

Is there any way to combine these into a single redirect? Or, is the landing page redirect not all that bad?

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st and 3rd redirect rules can be combined into one and should be kept before rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

#Then, rewrite to /catalog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /catalog/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I will let you know when I get a chance to test this.